# MySQL '@': what does it do?

Tags: mysql, variables

I'm following a tutorial [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). It keeps using '@' characters in front of stuff. Can I just confirm... does '@' identify variables within a query?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SET is used to give the variable an initial value.

For example:

```
SET @row := 0;

SELECT (@row := @row + 1) AS row, name FROM table;
```

If we don't give the variable an initial value, it would be NULL.

Comment: Thanks - perfect explanation. Welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 2):

It names a so-called "user variable".

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, '@' is used as a prefix for user defined variables. Find more information [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yup. MySQL's documentation has a section about [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html). You typically declare them with `SET` in MySQL, however I've seen other kinds of SQL use `DECLARE`.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, this is actually how you declare variables in mysql. Look at here:

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-storedproc.html

> The first thing we need to understand
>   is how user variables are used and
>   assigned values. A user variable is
>   distinguished by having a '@' symbol
>   in front of it, and values are
>   assigned using the SET statement:

Comment: @BoltClock - I do not appreciate rude comments. He never did mention in what context.

Comment: Intriguing - the tutorial I'm following uses stuff like `SELECT @myRight := rgt FROM nested_category`. Is that OK to use too?

Comment: Figured as much. I admit I was rather impatient, so I'll apologize. @JamWaffles, you may want to add an example snippet so it's clearer what you're referring to.

Comment: My bad - sorry to both of you :-) The original question, however, has been answered many times in this thread.